# How to get elevation data from XYZ source in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, elevation, xyz

I have an XYZ file. For each pair of latitude and longitude values, there is an elevation value in meters in the file.

How do I get those elevation values in Openlayers 3?

Basically, my map will have an event. On every mouse click, the elevation value will show up based on the latitude and longitude.